# How to pass enum as an argument in a method in java?

Tags: java, enums

```
public class Enumvalues{

    enum courseList {
        JAVA,
        C,
        PYTHON,
        PERL
    }

    enum generalInformation {
        NAME,
        AGE,
        PHONE
    }  

    enum sex {
        MALE,
        FEMALE
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
     printEnumValue(generalInformation); // how to pass enum in this block
}


static void printEnumValue(enum generalInformation) { // how to receive enum  in this block    
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(generalInformation.values()));
}
```

Answer (score 24):

> Note that your question has mixed up two different problems: Passing an Enum to a function OR Passing an Enum constant to a function. My understanding was that you want to pass the enum itself, not one of it's constants to the function. If not: refer to Narendra Pathai's answer on how to pass a single enum constant to a function. If you don't know what the difference between an enum and an enum constant is, review the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) about enums...

I Understand that what you want is to have a print (or any other) function where you can pass any possible enum, to print each of the enum's possible values (i.e. constants). I've found the following two approaches to do this:

Lets say we have the following enum:

```
// The test enum, any other will work too
public static enum ETest
{
    PRINT,MY,VALUES
}
```

**Variante 1:** Pass the array of constants from your enum to your function; As the enum's constants are static values, they can easily be accessed and passed to your 'print' function as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // retreive all constants of your enum by YourEnum.values()
    // then pass them to your function
    printEnum(ETest.values());
}

// print function: type safe for Enum values
public static <T extends Enum<T>> void printEnum(T[] aValues)
{
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(aValues));
}
```

**Variante 2:** Pass the enum's class as function parameter. This might look more beautiful, but be aware that reflection is involved (performance):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    printEnum2(ETest.class);
}

// print function: accepts enum class and prints all constants
public static <T extends Enum<T>> void printEnum2(Class<T> aEnum)
{
    // retreive all constants of your enum (reflection!!)
    System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.asList(aEnum.getEnumConstants()));
}
```

In my opinion, it's better to use variante 1 because of the overuse of reflection in variante 2. The only advantage that variante 2 gives you, is that you have the Class object of the Enum itself (the static enum, not only it's constants) inside your function, so I've mentioned it for completeness.

Answer (score 20):

An enum is a class. So you can pass an instance of the class (`EnumValues.generalInformation.PHONE` for example), or you can pass the class itself (`EnumValues.generalInformation.class` for example).

If you want to list all the instances of an enum class, you need to pass the enum class, and use `EnumSet.allOf(EnumValues.generalInformation.class)` for example.

Your confusion principally comes from the fact that you don't respect the Java naming conventions. ENums are classes and should start with an upper-case letter (`GeneralInformation` for example). An other source of confusion is the bad choice of names. JAVA is not a course list. It's a course. So the enum should be named `Course`.

Comment: This just gives me a null enum instance at the other end

Comment: how would you design a methd that can be invoked by passing any enum?

Answer (score 17):

If you want to pass a single value from the enum

```
    public class Test {

    enum GeneralInformation{
        NAME;
    }

    private static void print(GeneralInformation val){
        System.out.println(val);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(GeneralInformation.NAME);
    }
}
```

else if you want whole class to be passed then, as it was not clear from the question

```
private static void print(Class<?> generalInfo){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(GeneralInformation.class);
    }
```

Comment: As enum is just like any other class, do you want class literal? Then i had edited to use `Class<?>`

Comment: Or if you want all the instances of enum class then use `GeneralInformation.values()` which will give you GeneralInformation[] that includes all the instances of enum

Comment: Wow, **that's** useful: `cls.getEnumConstants()` Returns "an array containing the values comprising the enum class represented by this Class object in the order they're declared, or null if this Class object does not represent an enum type". Tested it. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

TestEnumMain.java:

```
package enumSample;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.EnumUtils; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean result= isValidEnum(DummyEnum.class, "APPLE"); 
        System.out.println("result= " + result); 
        boolean result2= isValidEnum2(DummyEnum.class, "COF"); 
        System.out.println("result2= " + result2); 
        //boolean result3= isValidEnum2(A_Different_Enum.class, "COF");  //works
        //System.out.println("result3= " + result3); 

    }

    public static<E extends Enum<E>> boolean isValidEnum2(Class<E> enumClass, String enumName) {

        System.out.println("enumClass.getEnumConstants().length= " + enumClass.getEnumConstants().length); 
        System.out.println("enumClass.getEnumConstants()[0]= " + enumClass.getEnumConstants()[0]); 
        System.out.println("enumClass.getEnumConstants()[1]= " + enumClass.getEnumConstants()[1].name()); 
        System.out.println("enumName.valueOf(enumClass)= "+ enumName.valueOf(enumClass));

        if(enumName== null) {
            return false; 
        } else {
            try {
                if(enumClass.isAssignableFrom(DummyEnum.class)) { /*Checks if enumClass is an instance of DummyEnum.class*/
                    for (int i=0; i!= enumClass.getEnumConstants().length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("(DummyEnum) enumClass.getEnumConstants()["+i+"]).code()= "+ ((DummyEnum) enumClass.getEnumConstants()[i]).code());          
                        if(enumName.equals(((DummyEnum) enumClass.getEnumConstants()[i]).code())) {
                            return true; 
                        }
                    }                   
                    return false; 
                } else {
                    Enum.valueOf(enumClass, enumName); 
                    return true; 
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException var3){
                return false; 
            }
        }

    }

    //Original Method from apache.commons.long3.EnumUtils: 
    public static<E extends Enum<E>> boolean isValidEnum(Class<E> enumClass, String enumName) {
        if(enumName== null) {
            return false; 
        } else {
            try {
                Enum.valueOf(enumClass, enumName); 
                return true; 
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException var3){
                return false; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

DummyEnum.java:

```
package enumSample;

public enum DummyEnum {
    APPLE("APP"), 
    GOOGLE("GOOG"), 
    CAPITAL_ONE("COF");

    private String code; 
    DummyEnum(String code) {this.code= code;}
    public String code() {return code;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`printEnumValue(EnumValues.generalInformation.NAME,EnumValues.generalInformation.AGE,EnumValues.generalInformation.PHONE);`

Receiving:

```
public static void printEnumValue(EnumValues.generalInformation en){
System.out.println(en.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An enum is used just like a type:

```
static void printEnumValue(courseList generalInformation) { // how to receive enum  in this block
```

used like:

`printEnumValue(courseList.JAVA);`

Answer (score 0):

enums are technically descendants of Enum class. So, if you want to use only Enum's standard methods in your method (such as values()), pass the parameter like this:
`static void printEnumValue(Enum generalInformation)`
See, that the only thing you have to change is the capital letter E.