# How to pass enumeration in to a method as argument?

Tags: java, enums

I have imported an API which includes an Enumeration. Now in a different class, I need to invoke a method which takes Enumeration as argument.

```
getValueDateByTenorType(Enumeration tenure)
```

But I have no idea how can I pass Enumeration as we cannot instantiate an Enumeration.

Comment: The API should have documentation on how to obtain the Enumeration

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414530/how-to-pass-enum-as-an-argument-in-a-method-in-java

Comment: Just to clarify, you're talking of [Java's Enumeration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)?

Comment: You can have a class which implements the "Enumeration" interface then create the instance of that class and pass it. See "java.util.StringTokenizer" class for your reference as it implements the "Enumeration" interface. Why would you think of instantiating an Enumeration?

Answer (score 1):

If the enum is in the same class you can pass the enum as shown below.

```
public class CollegeTenure{

     public enum TENURE{
          HALF_YEARLY, FULL_PROFESSORSHIP;
     }

     public void getValueDateByTenorType(TENURE tenure){     
          if( TENURE.HALF_YEARLY.equals( tenure ) ) {
             System.out.println("Half Yearly tenure");
          } else if( TENURE.FULL_PROFESSORSHIP.equals( tenure ) ) {
              System.out.println("Full Professorship tenure");
          }

      }

      public static void main(String[]args) {
          CollegeTenure collegeTenure = new  CollegeTenure();
          collegeTenure.getValueDateByTenorType(TENURE.HALF_YEARLY);
      }
}
```

enum can also be defined in another class as public

```
public class Constants{
         public enum TENURE{
              HALF_YEARLY, FULL_PROFESSORSHIP;
         }    
}

public class CollegeTenure2{

          public void getValueDateByTenorType(Constants.TENURE tenure){     
              if( Constants.TENURE.HALF_YEARLY.equals( tenure ) ) {
                 System.out.println("Half Yearly tenure");
              } else if( Constants.TENURE.FULL_PROFESSORSHIP.equals( tenure ) ) {
                  System.out.println("Full Professorship tenure");
              }

          }

          public static void main(String[]args) {
              CollegeTenure2 collegeTenure2 = new  CollegeTenure2();
              CollegeTenure2.getValueDateByTenorType(Constants.TENURE.FULL_PROFESSORSHIP);
          }
}
```

Comment: aren't [Enumeration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) and [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) different in Java?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with that Enumeration/Function, (provide more information for a more detailed answer) but most generally speaking, you have either to use any existing class that implements the Enumeration interface, (e.g. `Collections.enumeration(myList)`) or you have to build one on your own. This would be done as follows:

```
// User defined type specific Enumeration
// implements java.util.Enumeration Interface
class MyEnumeration<T> implements Enumeration<T>
{
    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements()
    {
        // provide boolean function to check if your Enumeration
        // has more elements
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public T nextElement()
    {
        // provide function that returns the next element
        return null;
    }
}
```

This class can then be passed to your API function (yet, you still have to know what is done inside this function to know what your Enumeration should contain):

```
getValueDateByTenorType(new MyEnumeration<String>());
```

You can add as many functions as you want to create or modify your Enumeration class, but you have to provide the two interface methods `hasMoreElements` and `nextElement`. For more information, review the documentation about [Enumerations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html)
 and [Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html).