# Java - How to throw IllegalArgumentException for out of class variable

Tags: java, oop, exception

I have to model a Television class which holds a TV's current channel number.

```
public class Television {

    private int channel;

    public Television(int channel) {

        this.channel = channel;
    }
```

Afterward, I have to create a setter for the channel.

```
    public void setChannel(int channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
    }
```

Then I have to create a new class with *two constructors*:

The first one has no arguments and sets a new int, channel limit, to 10:

```
public class ChannelLimit {

    int chLimit;

    public ChannelLimit() {
        chLimit = 10;
    }
```

**The problem:**

A second one that takes chLimit as a parameter and throws an IllegalArgumentException whenever the channel that I set is below 0 or above the channel limit.

What I'm struggling with: I can't find an easy way to access the newly set channel(s).

My first guess is to use a getter, but if I have multiple objects, will I have to write a setter for each and every one of them?

Comment: can you put second constructors code too?

Comment: Maybe pass the parameter as a enum, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414530/how-to-pass-enum-as-an-argument-in-a-method-in-java

Comment: If possible it is not good to throw exceptions from constructors.

Comment: How are you going to connect these Television and ChannelLimit classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was written poorly and I would like to provide a solution.

Basically, I didn't need to throw an error when the channel was higher than the channel limit.

I had to build two constructors, one which sets the channel limit to 10 automatically and one who throws an error when trying to set the channel limit below 0.

Basically all I had to do was:

Declare chLimit as an int and put it in the main television constructor:

```
public Television(int channel, int chLimit) {

        this.channel = channel;
        this.chLimit = chLimit;

    }
```

Then create 2 constructors:

One without arguments that automatically sets it to 10:

```
public Television() {
      this.chLimit = 10;
    }
```

Another one that takes CH_LIMIT as an argument and throws IAE is lower than 0.

```
public Television(int chLimit) {

if (chLimit < 0) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
    }
    else {
          this.chLimit = chLimit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should created getter and setter for each property in your class , its called [1.1.1.5 Encapsulation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/Java-overview.html#GUID-68EE1A7B-1F78-4074-AB76-AF9B2CE878F6)

> Encapsulation describes the ability of an object to hide its data and methods from the rest of the world and is one of the fundamental principles of object-oriented programming.

In your code `channel` is private so you can't access it outside the class.
so there is 2 ways.

1. change you access to public then you will able to access `channel` directly. "Not a good idea"
2. create getter and setter for property in your class.

Comment: I already have a getter in my Television class. However, I don't know how to access it in the error class.

For example, I create a new object in the Main class and I set the channel to -4 using setChannel();

Now, if I use getChannel(); in the main class, the channel is successfully changed. 

However I don't know access that value it in the error class. Do I need another getter in the main class?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the problem fully.
you want to create one more constructor like below

```
    public ChannelLimit(int chLimit) {
        if (chLimit < 0 || chLimit > MAX)
           {
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid chLimit");
           }
             this.chLimit = chLimit;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to create a getter method in `Television` class.

```
public int getChannel() {
    return channel;
}
```

I am suggesting you to this kind of solution:

```
public ChannelLimit(int chLimit) {
    Television television = new Television(5);
    if (television.getChannel() < 0 || television.getChannel() > chLimit) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid argument");
    } else {
        this.chLimit = chLimit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, and why you need two classes to do it, but if you really want these two classes, I would suggest to do something like this:

```
public class ChannelLimit {
    int final chLimit;

    public ChannelLimit() {
        this(10);
    }

    public ChannelLimit(int chLimit) {
        this.chLimit = chLimit;
    }

    public void check(int channel) {
        if (channel < 0 || channel > chLimit) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid channel number");
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can either use an instance of `ChannelLimit` as a a field in class `Television`, in which case, You'll want to add a `ChannelLimit` parameter to your constructor:

```
public class Television {
    private final ChannelLimit channelLimit;
    private int channel;

    public Television(ChannelLimit channelLimit, int channel) {
        channelLimit.check(channel);
        this.channelLimit = channelLimit;
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public Television(int channel) {
        this(new ChannelLimit(), channel);
    }

    public void setChannel(int channel) {
        channelLimit.check(channel);
        this.channel = channel;
    }
}
```

Or you can inherit `ChannelLimit`:

```
public class Television extends ChannelLimit {
    private int channel;

    public Television(int chLimit, int channel) {
        super(chLimit);
        check(channel);
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    // use the default constructor with a limit of 10 channels
    public Television(int channel) {
        check(channel);
        this.channel = channel;
    }

    public void setChannel(int channel) {
        check(channel);
        this.channel = channel;
    }
}
```

I would use the first approach since a television is not a channel limit, but **has** a channel limit.

Comment: What's bugging me is that I specifically have to throw the IllegalArgumentException from a constructor, not a method. I do not clearly understand this requirement as it's way easier to do it from a method.

Comment: @flowz0r you could inline the code of the `check` method, but you would need an accessor for the `chLimit`, unless you use the second approach, and make `chLimit` `protected` instead of `private`.

Comment: @flowz0r but this doesn't make a lot of sense.